# Rewrite rule using RealUrl

Tags: typo3, realurl

I need to set up a forwarding for the following:

www.mysite.com/example/page.html - this no longer exists

that forwards to a page that is generated by TYPO3 using realurl

www.mysite.com/examples/thenewpage/

I've tested several mod_rewrite rules but they don't appear to be taking effect. Is it the case that I need to add some sort of rule to my realurl.conf?

(My setup
TYPO3 v 7.6.13
realurl v 2.1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the default TYPO3 htaccess you should add your rule before those TYPO3 RewriteRules. Somewhere at line 280 or earlier.

Anyway I prefer using extensions for those redirects like my_redirects. It has a nice backend module for handling those redirects. https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/my_redirects